# Compiling Flash on Linux

Tags: linux, flash, apache-flex

I'm new to the ColdFusion scene, and am the CM at my company. Most of my experience is with C, C++, and Java builds.

We have one ColdFusion project that I need to compile. It contains a bunch of ActionScripts, CFM files, and the `build.xml` has the following lines in it:

```
<exec executable="C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS3\flash.exe"
    searchpath="true"
    <arg line="compilePoroject.jsfl"/>
</exec>
```

Our build machine is a Linux box, so I would like to be able to build this in Linux. I don't need to do development on Linux, so I don't care if there's no Linux Flash IDE. I just need to compile whatever I need to compile.

There are a bunch of `*.as` files which I assume are action scripts that need to be compiled. There are also `*.fla` files that I believe are Adobe Vector Graphics files.

I downloaded Apache's Flex project, but the Readme file says that it depends upon some third party assets (Adobe) and won't work without them. However, the Flex project contains a `mxmlc.jar` and a `mxmlc` binary that executes the jar. There doesn't appear to be any Windows based dependency on this process.

All I want to do is compile and build the project. I don't need to edit these files. I just need to build the SWF files. Can I do it with the `mxmlc` compiler on my Linux box? Is it possible to restructure everything to be able to build using my Linux box?

Comment: It should be, however there are some libraries that are commonly used which I think only come with the flash-ide. If i remember correctly it's the ones that start with `flash`

Comment: .flas are project files used w/ Flash Professional.  I don't think you'll be able to do anything with them on Linux or the command line.  If the bulk of your app is in an FLA then the Flex compiler can't help you.

Comment: @David W. I haven't tried it, but hopefully you can run a version of Flash through [Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=23) on Linux. If it's an actionscript-3 project, you could migrate the project from the Flash IDE to Flash Builder/Flex IDE but it's a manual process AFAIK. In the easiest case, the Flash project would have an as3 Document Class and probably use symbols exported for actionscript in the library, in which case, it should be simple enough to export a .swc library from Flash which can be linked against in Flex similar to how you link a .jar ...

Comment: ...in Java/eclipse. If you have timeline code, there's a bit more manual labour, but still shouldn't take too long. You can either try using the Flash IDE with Wine on Linux or simply borrowing/using Windows to migrate the project to the Flex IDE. Worst case scenario, it's an older actionscript 2.0 project, in which case you can still export .swf files for the assets and use an opensource as2.0 compiler like [mtasc](http://www.mtasc.org/). HTH

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I used Wine a few times, but it's not really that complete. Wine is trying to duplicate all calls, errors, and side-effects that happens with all Windows calls. Such a task is Herculean in nature and requires resources that most open source projects can only dream of. Not only is Windows a constantly shifting target, but is simply not as important as it once was. If this was a personal project, I wouldn't mind, but this is a company with millions of customers. Good news is that this project has just been deprecated and will be replaced by the end of the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer is that you can't. You need the Adobe libraries to do anything with the FLA files. There are *open source* projects for compiling, but these are mostly in the extended *alpha* stage and are missing features and have all sorts of bugs. They might be good enough for a small site, but not a commercial adventure where millions of customers are hitting this page.